# WatchKit - iPhone not available screen

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2, pairing

Since i migrated my project to **watchOS2** - the "iPhone not available" screen suddenly  disappeared.

In **OS1** this was a "default" behaviour, now the watch has it's own dataset, which creates issues when i try to sync the watch and phone together.

My question is - how do i check if the phone is paired on not, stop performing any actions (like in **OS1**) if it's not and bring back that screen?

Screen example: http://belencruz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/IMG_20150624_175906-e1435296319135-1024x979.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `paired` on `WCSession` instance.

```
import WatchConnectivity

if WCSession.defaultSession().paired {

}
```

#### paired

> A Boolean indicating whether the current iPhone is paired to an Apple Watch. (read-only)

Also you defiantly have to check `watchAppInstalled`.

> A Boolean value indicating whether the Watch app is installed on the currently paired and active Apple Watch. (read-only)

Comment: Also, the `reachable` property is important to mention, and the `WCSessionDelegate` callbacks that notify the delegate of various state changes.